# Upload input image file to database with BLOB datatype Vuejs

Tags: oracle, vue.js, axios

We have a form that must save image file to our database with blob datatype

what i currently did is convert the file to dataURL and dataURL to BLOB

```
selectFile(){
            
            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.$refs.file.files[0])
            reader.onload = () => {
                var dataURL = reader.result;
                console.log(dataURL);

                var arr = dataURL.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
                bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
                while(n--){
                u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
                }
            
                var file =  new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
                console.log(test);
                this.file = file 
            }

                
        
        },
```

and from the console it was successful i was able to convert IMG to dataURL to Blob, the problem is when submitting the form, so i have a axios

```
async OnSubmit() {
            this.loading = true;
            const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('first_name', this.first_name);
                formData.append('signature_1_1', this.file);
                const config = { 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                 } 
                
                };
            
            try{
                let{data, status, response} = await  
                axios.post('/api/auth/register', formData ,
                config);

                this.loading = false;

                if ([201, 200].indexOf(status) > -1) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "Success!",
                        text: `Successfully Register RE Developer!`,
                        icon: "success",
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        showCancelButton: false,
                        confirmButtonText: "Close",
                        }).then((result) => {
                            this.$router.push({ name: "login" });
                    });
                }
                catch (error) {
                // this.errors = `${error.errors}`;
                this.loading = false;

                Swal.fire({
                title: "Oops!",
                text: `Something went wrong!`,
                icon: "error",
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                showCancelButton: false,
                confirmButtonText: "Close",
                });
            }
```

based on the headers the blob is there
[image]

but Im still getting error "Error Code    : 1465\r\nError Message : ORA-01465: invalid hex number
and i also tried the direct approach which is "formData.append('signature_1_1', this.$ref.file.files[0]);" but same error

Register Controller

```
function register(Request, $request){
   $validated_data= TableValidate::validateTable($request);
   
   $data= Table::create($validated_data);
 }
```

For Validation

```
public static function validateTable(Request $request) {
 $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required|string',
            
    )];
    $data = [
      'first_name' => $request->first_name,
      'signature_1_1' => $request->signature_1_1,
      ]

}
```

I hope someone can help me with this

Comment: But where is the Oracle code or something that accesses the database?

Comment: @astentx I don't think I have an issue with database connection because I'm able to submit the form if the Input File field is empty.

Comment: Of course empty data is not an issue. You need to know how the data is passed into the database

Comment: @astentx if you mean the controller and validation i added it, but i dont have any validation for signature_1_1 field ('the one i'm getting an error')